# How to pass Conditional argument in PostgreSQL using go?

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm stuck over to pass argument to the `Exec` function on the basis of some conditions. I googled for this but found the solution with MySQL to use `args := []interface{}{var1, var2, ... varN}`.

But my problem with PostgreSQL below is my conditional query:

```
strQry := `UPDATE core_channel SET title = $1, description = $2, `

if updateChannelReq.FeaturedVideo != 0 {
    strQry += `default_video_id = $3, `
}

strQry += ` original_keywords = $4, banner_link = $5 WHERE create_user_id = $6`
```

And here how I'm passing argument to execute this query:

```
args := []interface{}{
        updateChannelReq.Title,
        updateChannelReq.Description,
    }

if updateChannelReq.FeaturedVideo != 0 {
    args = append(args, updateChannelReq.FeaturedVideo)
}

args = []interface{}{
    updateChannelReq.OriginalKeyWords,
    updateChannelReq.BannerLink,
    AuthUserID,
}

_, err = stmt.Exec(args...)
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
pq: could not determine data type of parameter $3
```

please help me that how to manage these things.
Thanks.

Comment: @JigneshMistry: as long as your edits need reviewing, make sure to fix as much as possible. That single capital in the title was by far not the only thing that needs to be corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Change the condition by using else condition to skip the third column when creating query string.

```
strQry := `UPDATE core_channel SET title = $1, description = $2, `

if updateChannelReq.FeaturedVideo != 0 {
    strQry += `default_video_id = $3, original_keywords = $4, banner_link = $5 WHERE create_user_id = $6 `
} else {
    strQry += ` original_keywords = $3, banner_link = $4 WHERE create_user_id = $5`
}
```